# How to create correct url in tepmplate Django

Tags: django, templates, django-urls

I have this link in my templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'main:user-main-account' %}?=client_account{{ client_account.id }}">
```

like a link it looks like:

```
https://mysite.ua/main/user_main_account/?=client_account=1
```

How can I change my template link to get link like this:

```
https://mysite.ua/main/client_account/1/user_main_accounts
```

My 2 urls in urls.py look like this:

```
path('user_main_account/<int:pk>/', ........)
path('client_account'/<int:pk>/'.........)
```

Please help me!I am stuck of 3 days.

Comment: You should add the whole `path(...)` definition as it most likely contains the URL's name...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data into the `url` tag it will be like

```
{% url 'main:user-main-account' client_account.id %}
```

this will generate the URL you looking for also Read the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)